# Patenting PRISM - Classifying Mobile Users Based on Social Analysis of Who calls Whom (Ericsson) - Patent Application - PRIOR ART REQUEST

Tags: prior-art-request, pre-grant, social-networking, us20130138479, ericsson

**AN OVERBROAD PATENT ON classifying mobile users based on who they call in a network** - This application from [Ericsson](http://www.ericsson.com/us) seeks to patent the idea of...Social network analysis applied to mobile phones...Keep [PRISM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PRISM_%28surveillance_program%29) free of patent licenses!  10 minutes of your time can help narrow US patent applications before they become patents.  [Follow @askpatents](https://twitter.com/AskPatents) on twitter to help.

**QUESTION** - Have you seen anything that was **published before 5/24/2010** that discusses:

> - Social network analysis to classify individuals in a community based on who they communicate with

If so, please submit evidence of prior art as an answer to this question. We welcome multiple answers from the same individual.

**EXTRA CREDIT** - A reference to anything that meets all of the criteria to the question above AND ALSO involves demographic information about users.

**TITLE: Social network analysis on cell phone calling networks to segment users**

**Summary**:  [Translated from Legalese into English]

- **Publication Number**: [US20130138479 A1](http://www.google.com/patents/us20130138479)
- **Application Number**: US 13/699,796
- **Assignee**:
- **Prior Art Date**: Seeking prior Art **predating** 5/24/2010
- **Open for Challenge at USPTO:** Open through 11/26/2013

**Claim 1** requires each and every step below:

> A method for classifying a new mobile user in a communication network based on demographics associated with the new mobile user, the method comprising:
>
> 1. Representing, for a sample set of mobile users, each mobile user in the sample set by a node and mobile usage between two nodes by an edge connecting the two nodes;
> 2. Forming one or more communities of nodes;
> 3. Identifying a plurality of demographic subunits by splitting each of the one or more communities;
> 4. Determining one or more structural properties associated with each of the plurality of subunits;
> 5. Mapping the one or more structural properties to demographics of the plurality of subunits; and
> 6. Classifying the new mobile user based on the determined structural properties.

In English this means:

> A method for classifying a new user in a communication network, comprising:
>
> 1. Creating a graph structure with users as nodes and edges as communication between users
> 2. Forming communities of nodes (using any clustering technique)
> 3. Looking for correlation between demographic features of groups of nodes (e.g. rich, white, parent, etc…) and structural features of same groups of nodes (all communicate with one another, for example)
> 4. Classifying a new user based on these structural features (i.e. who he talk to)

Good prior art would be evidence of a system that did each and every one of these steps prior to 5/24/2010

You're probably aware of ten pieces of art that meet this criteria already... separately, the applicant is claiming segmenting customers based on **standard clustering algorithms** applied to a social graph

---

**"Determining and presenting demographics of mobile users in a communication network from the Applicant"**

[image]

---

*What is good prior art? Please see our [FAQ](https://patents.stackexchange.com/faq#prior-art).*

*Want to help? Please vote or comment on submissions below. We welcome you to [post your own request for prior art](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prior-art-request+pre-grant) on other questionable US Patent Applications.*

---

Answer (score 1):

Does this also suggest number of communications like amount of connections or it just considers 2 nodes connected using 1 connection and analysis of nodes.

I mean does it say that analysis would include how much time it took for the connection to stay live and also take into account how many time a connection was live etc.

Comment: No necessary limitation. In U.S., inventors may "act as their own lexicographer" in a patent application. That means that an inventor may give a common word or phrase a meaning that is very specific and different from the normal definition of said word or phrase. Thus a claim must be interpreted in light of the definitions provided in the specification of a patent. The specification for US20130138479 gives a number of examples but doesn't limit the analysis to the time connections remain live or frequency of connection. The only limitation is that method must contain each claim element above!